# armature to unfold a chinese food box to a flat page

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm working on an animation and I'm trying to build an armature to unfold a chinese food box like this one; to a flat paper page:

[image]

Once flat, it should look like this :

[image]

But I've got hard times to make the armature work.
It's no problem to have the main faces working; but I don't know how to handle the paper "folds" in the corners...
I've already tested by assigning manually several times and in different ways the vertexes weights; but I don't get any convincing results.

[image]

How would you do / can someone help ?  Here's [my actual file](https://filedn.eu/lDv4C27hDkbRzM3b8NHRBTz/blendswap-chinese-food-03.blend).

Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, the best I've come up with adds two more bones to each of the four corners and requires manually animating at least two of the corners.  Have you looked into doing in the opposite direction with an add-on like [orgamify](https://github.com/aconz2/blender-addon-origamify) or even just doing it with a series of shape keys?

Answer (score 6):

You have only 1 bone for each corner. Why not use 2 bones so each can control a "face area" as seen in the 2nd reference image?

[image: bones layout]
<sup>Frame 1 - Areas of influence of the bones</sup>

Then add a keyframe for the rotation of the bones at frame 25 and bring them on roughly the same height as the sides of the box. But let it bend a bit because the cardboard material can not compact:

[image: frame 25]
<sup>Frame 25</sup>

Then edit the end frame (50) and fold in the two paper folds as shown in the reference illustration. Try to bring the bones in position by rotating them around the X and Z-axis. Then rotate them around the Y-axis to create the folds and if the mesh intersects or is twisted:

[image: frame 50]
<sup>Frame 50</sup>

Blender will calculate the frames in between, but the animation might not look right. For example, intersections can occur at short notice. So you need to adjust the bone rotation at frame 35 a little bit and get them to a good place:

[image: frame 35]
<sup>Frame 35</sup>

**Animation (50 frames)**:

[image: final animation]