# Preserving surface area while bending

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to mimic real world bending in blender so that for example a sheet of paper would be having the same surface area as you bend it?

Comment: Assuming you're using a plane for paper, not a thin cube, this might help -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239379/looping-paper-fold-out-animation/240132#240132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean like this:

[image]

yes, you can.

Add a curve.
Add a plane and subdivide it a few times.

Add a curve modifier to your plane, curve object: spiral

[image]

Animate the location of the plane. Ready.

[image]