# Flatpack Boxes Suggested Workflow

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been given the task of creating packaging imagery for a box supplier (thrilling I know) and I was wondering what the best way to go about it would be?

The products in question are sustainable take out food containers. Pizza, noodles, burgers, etc. They have been supplied to me in their unassembled form.

I have created a mesh ( see below ) with the intention of folding it into it's constructed form, however I anticipate running into trouble with the bent corners and the solidify modifier.

Would it be better to model the box in its assembled state? For what its worth I have about 12 different box styles to do.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can go in both ways [unfold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161399/2214) or [fold](https://vimeo.com/47946882) in case I got a cutting data from factory ... with "Mesh Convert to Armature" addon ... problematic could be the corners due script is looking for tree hierarchy also you would have to probably add some more edges simulate paper thickness not all can be solved by Solidify :)

Comment: The link below might help to get you familiar with folding etc but if you are to present the packaging in it's assembled form, at a guess I'd say it would be easier to model it that way in the first place.  The folding link -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239379/looping-paper-fold-out-animation/240132#240132