# How do I keep my object from going through itself?

Tags: physics, properties, soft-body

I am trying to create a mockup of a zine to place onto a website. It is made from a plane being folded to replicate a piece of paper. When I fold it the second time for some reason the backside keeps going through the front, I'm using AnimAll for the vertex animation and have tried moving those vertexes numerous times but nothing seems to work. I'm sure this is a simple answer but I can't seem to find the answer to this online either, any help?

Comment: If I remember you must enable "goals"

Comment: @Yvain it is already enabled!

Comment: Screenshot, Blendfile, are you using cloth...?

Comment: no it is just a plane being folded, I didn't apply any physics or properties yet but have tried several that did not work

Comment: I wonder if this would help? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239379/looping-paper-fold-out-animation/240132#240132